# How would I go about creating an extension to preview GTFS data in CKAN?

Tags: plugins, preview, gtfs, ckan

I want to create an extension to preview GTFS data - though my question is more about just how to create an extension to preview data.

Looking through the documentation and code I've [found.](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.0/extensions.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IResourcePreview)

And these examples of existing preview extension:

- [PDF](https://github.com/okfn/ckan/tree/master/ckanext/pdfpreview)
- [Text (including JSON)](https://github.com/okfn/ckan/tree/master/ckanext/textpreview)
- [GeoJSON](https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-spatial/blob/master/ckanext/spatial/nongeos_plugin.py#L43)

Is there an example of an absolutely minimal extension to do previewing or tips on how I would go about this for GTFS (what's the best example to base my work off)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you have a look at the Text preview extension. It is reasonably small and covers all important parts such as how to let CKAN know that the extension can preview a file, how to load templates, how to load javascript and css and how to use the resource proxy (which is there to get around the same origin policy).

The [current version of the plugin](https://github.com/okfn/ckan/blob/b3424e587e622ff1d345de8e6a80a1535bd6a514/ckanext/textpreview/plugin.py) in CKAN uses a feature that allows defining how reasonable an extension can preview files which is not available in older CKANs.

There is a [json preview extension](https://github.com/okfn/ckan/tree/release-v2.0.2/ckanext/jsonpreview) in the stable version 2.0 of CKAN which is slightly smaller that the text-preview and supports older CKANs as well.

A minimal preview plugin looks something like (without the template):

```
import ckan.plugins as p

class Preview(p.SingletonPlugin):
    p.implements(p.IResourcePreview, inherit=True)

    def can_preview(self, data_dict):
        format = data_dict['resource']['format']
        return format.lower() == 'gtfs'

    def preview_template(self, context, data_dict):
        return 'preview.html'
```

Comment: could you provide *inline* an absolutely minimal example of how do a previewer plugin (minimal = no templating etc ...) :-)

Comment: @RufusPollock I added a super small example.